# java AtomicInteger decrementAndGet does not work as expected

Tags: java, concurrency

The AtomicInteger's decrementAndGet does not seems working correctly in multi-threaded operation. Though the incrementAndGet works correctly. I run this program from the Executors and in 10 threads. Each thread is decrementing the value 5 times in the loop so 10 threads will reduce its value to -50. But I do not get the value -50. Same thing if I do for calling incrementAndGet then, it does increase to 50.

```
public class RunCountAtomic {

public static  AtomicInteger aValue = new AtomicInteger(0);

public void runLoop() {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
//      aValue.getAndIncrement();
            doSomeWork();
            aValue.decrementAndGet();
        }
    System.out.println(" Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: " +aValue.get());
    }
    // Some dummy work!     
    public void doSomeWork() { try {Thread.sleep(100);  } catch (InterruptedException e) {}  } 
}
```

The result shows that incrementAndGet does work correctly but not the decrementAndGet! Does anyone of you also have such observation? Or I might be missing something in the code.

Below is the test code which calls the method of above class:

[Updated as per reply comment]
Update my TestMainRL code to use executor service to simplify it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int noOfThreads         = 10;
    ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads); 

    List<Future<Boolean>>   fblist = new ArrayList<Future<Boolean>>(noOfThreads);  

    System.out.println("Starting");     
    // Run the async task in multiple threads.
    for (int i = 0; i<noOfThreads; i++) {
        TestMainRL t = new TestMainRL();
        fblist.add(t.asyncTask ( e));
    }

    //Just to wait all thread to complete.
    //try {for(Future<Boolean> fb: fblist) {fb.get();}} catch (Exception e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
    e.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Completed!");

}
```

BTW, below is the result to show that last thread is not -50:

```
Starting
Completed!
Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main] Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: -42
Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main] Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: -42
Thread[pool-1-thread-6,5,main] Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: -46
Thread[pool-1-thread-7,5,main] Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: -50
Thread[pool-1-thread-5,5,main] Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: -49
Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main] Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: -49
Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main] Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: -49
Thread[pool-1-thread-10,5,main] Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: -46
Thread[pool-1-thread-8,5,main] Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: -46
Thread[pool-1-thread-9,5,main] Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: -46
```

After getting the reply from @acm, I realized to achieve the goal that only one of the thread should print -50 and it would be possible with below code, which does not use ReentrantLock with below code of RunCountAtomic:

```
public class RunCountAtomic {
    public static  AtomicInteger aValue = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public void runLoop() {
        int x = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
           doSomeWork();
           x = aValue.decrementAndGet(); // decrement and store it in local x.
       }
       // Here at the time of this query post, I was printing aValue.get() instead of using stored x,
       // which will ensure that only one thread will have -50.
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" Value in thread " +x);
    }
    public void doSomeWork() { 
        try {
             Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
    } // Some dummy work!
}
```

The thread getting -50 is the last thread, which did the last decrement. But while doing system.out it may not be printing at the end.

Comment: Almost certainly it's because the `for` loop finishes before all threads have completed their work.  The *last* thread prints "-50", yes?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you choose to supply the  executor service` with a thread factory that returns daemon threads instead of calling `e.shutdown()` at the end of your program? Obviously, you don't need an orderly shutdown in _this_ program, but its a smart thing to do in the general case, and it would have been fewer lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for replies. @markspace : reply is quite logical, thanks, but actual result is: that at random some thread is -50 not (always) the last one. Now how to know the last one, I presume the one which prints last on the system.out (that may be misleading?). Most of the time the last one is -50, but some time no. I just wanted to get whether every thread had executed and when the last thread is ending then I do the clean up. I am choosing the incrementAndGet, which has never failed in the above (repeated) tests, but decrementAndGet looks not reliable or I am not using it correctly.Thanks.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thank you. I simplified it. Btw, now it shutdown in the order of completion. So the last thread should be showing -50 but it does not. Shall I doubt the jvm CAS not working on my processor, or still I am not using the code correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: Printing involves a lock. It is very likely that all threads are waiting to lock on the printstream (or better: it's lock). Locks in java are not fair. Which means, the last thread to retrieve the -50 may get the lock before others.

Comment: Right.  Printing doesn't happen in the same order as the threads execute.  Always assume that print statements are out of order when dealing with threads.  @JohannesKuhn Good point about unfair locks, I had forgotten about those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you expecting exactly? All threads to return `-50`, last thread to return `-50`? Non of that is guaranteed in the code you have provided.

`AtomicInteger` is behaving as expected. The guarantee you do have is that at least one of the threads will return `-50`, and that's happening right?

The key point is `System.out.println` -> `PrintStream#println`:

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

So all your thread are calling this but there is not fairness in this type of lock. So even though the last thread to arrive at this lock was the one with value `-50` it might not be the first one to get printed, so you have the guarantee that `-50` is printed but at some point not last.

To test what explaining you can use a `ReentrantLock` with fairness to true, meaning that the oldest waiting thread will be waked up first. Change `RunCountAtomic` as follows:

```
public class RunCountAtomic {
    private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    public static AtomicInteger aValue = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void runLoop() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            doSomeWork();
            aValue.decrementAndGet();
        }
        printlnValue(aValue.get());
    }

    private void printlnValue(int value) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println(" Expected value is - (5 x 10 thread = -50) , actual is: " + value);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void doSomeWork() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

Now you are guaranteed to have `-50` printed last.

Comment: Yes one of the thread is -50. Your reply "at least one thread is guaranteed to return -50" made it clear to me what is happening here. I was blinded that incrementAndGet was always (I tried 25 times) showing all thread 50. After this reply I realized that there is some 100ms sleep just after incrementAndGet and during that time it gets time that all thread gets incremented. Also realized that I should store value locally, updated the code, now only one thread will print -50. Thread printing -50 will be last thread right? syso print can be in different order. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You don't have any additional guarantee with the code you have changed. Imagine thread with value `-49` left the the loop stops there before you print. During that time your thread with value `-50` reaches the print and your `-49` for example continues and is printed last. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe you need a new question for that.